# using sqlserver 2008 in django1.8

Tags: django

Our workplace is invested in sqlserver2008 Ser but  can't support django1.8 , MSSQL1.7 is not support django1.8,django-pyodbc-azure is also not working

Are there any other ways for sqlserver2008 that are well django1.8?  What are your experiences?

Comment: That's not MSSQL1.7 ，is  django-mssql

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL1.8 is released, upgrate it in django, all is solved